# all of a sudden Laravel 5.1 can't retrieve logged user

Tags: laravel, authentication

I don't know what happened here, all of a sudden, out of the blue the code

```
return \Auth::user();
```

after loggin a user in isn't fetching anything. If I do  `echo $id =  \Auth::user()->id;`
I get a "ErrorException in UserController.php line 20:
Trying to get property of non-object" error.
The only thing I did before this happened was inserting:

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
{
    var_dump($query);
});
```

in my routes to display the sql queries, and removing that doesn't cure.

Comment: show us UserController file

Comment: ... after removing the query dump from routes it started working again!